# Infinite loop while using Scanner to read file Java

Tags: java

So I am trying to parse text files that could be in the form

```
words words words werdz words
```

or

```
words
words
words
words
words
```

Because of this, I decided to use Scanner instead of BufferedReader, and I'm not very experienced with using Scanner. I am trying to read a file and save to a Collection. Here is the main code and the supplementary methods.

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        LinkedList<String> unmodDict = readDict(new File(args[0]));
        String[] unsorted = readUnsorted(new File(args[1]));

        ...

}
```

readDict()

```
public static LinkedList<String> readDict(File file) throws IOException {
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        int count = 0;
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            ll.add(s.next());
        }
        // this loop seems to run finitely.
        s.close();
        return ll;
    }
```

readUnsorted()

```
public static String[] readUnsorted(File file) throws IOException {
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            count++;
        }
        reader.close();
        // The above loop is running infinitely.

        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        String line2 = null;
        String[] unsortedWerdz = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        while (reader2.hasNext()) {
            unsortedWerdz[i] = reader2.next();
            i++;
        }
        reader2.close();

        return unsortedWerdz;
    }
```

For some reason, the first while loop in the readUnsorted method is running infinitely but I can't see why since the first loop in the readDict method seems to run fine. Could someone advise me on what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It run's forever, since you check if there's a next `String` avaiable, but you don't retrieve it!
You need to get it via `next()` like this:

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();
            count++;
        }
```

Otherwise the `Scanner` will always point at the same (the first) element it reads and always report: `Yes, there's another token in here!`

Comment: Most times the smallest things are the easiest to overlook, feel free to accept so that others see the question was solved :)